# Java Web Start: How to get rid of the warning icon?

Tags: java, certificate, java-web-start

My java web start application always displays a warning icon in the top-right corner of the window. This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Warning icon]

I'd like to get rid of it. I have tried to sign my application without purchasing any certificate, just using `jarsigner`, but the icon is still there. In the other hand, if I don't sign the application at all, the icon is there as well. To be precise, i must say that my application runs in the basic sandbox.

Can I get rid of this ugly icon ? I don't like it because I will target a public & general audience, and some people might misinterpret its meaning. Would purchasing a certificate from an authority help in removing this icon ?

And in case it is related to my question, this is my `jnlp` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" 
        codebase="http://localhost:8080/bin/" 
        href="xxx-webstart.jnlp">
        <information>
            <title>xxx.com</title>
            <vendor>xxx.com</vendor>
        </information>
        <resources>
            <!-- Application Resources -->
            <j2se version="1.6+"
                  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
            <jar href="xxx.jar" main="true" />

        </resources>
        <application-desc
             name="xxx.com"
             main-class="com.xxx.client.swing.main.MainClientSwing"
             width="400"
             height="400">
         </application-desc>
         <update check="always" policy="always"/>
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: The JNLP file is invalid.  Try checking it with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code is signed (with any certificate, self-signed or verified), declares `j2ee-application-client-permissions` or `all-permissions` & is accepted by the user, the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a real code-signing certificate. Self-signed certificates are not considered secure thus warnings will be displayed.